# Import nor require are working inside my jest test files in my node.js app

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babeljs, require

I just installed jest into my node.js app. I can run `npm test` just fine, until I attempt to import something from another file.

I have a file called `channel.test.js` and I've tried the following:

```
import { emptyChannelSortingQueue } from './channels.js'
import * as channel from './channels.js'
var channel = require('./channels.js')
```

Inside my `package.json`, I already have `"type": "module"`.

I'm still getting this error:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
>
> Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
>
> By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.
>
> Here's what you can do:
>
> - If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
> - If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
> - To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
> - If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
> - If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
>
> You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
> For information about custom transformations, see:
> https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation
>
> Details:
>
> /Users/alishahome/Documents/Software_Engineering/megara/bot/src/utils/channels.js:1
> ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import {
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I tried changing out this line in my dockerfile

```
RUN npm install --quiet
```

to:

```
RUN npm install --quiet --experimental-vm-modules
```

I also tried adding this to my `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "mjs"],
    "transform": {},
    "moduleNameMapper": {}
  }
```

I also tried installing babel/jest and putting this in a `babel.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          node: "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing to add this to my package.json

```
"test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npm exec jest"
"type": "module"
```